# PHP 5.6 Repository URL for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Tags: php, repository, ubuntu-14.04, updates, php-5.6

I have PHP 5.6.18-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 and am trying to update to 5.6.19. However, when I do apt-get update && apt-get upgrade, PHP does not get updated.

I have tried `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6` as well as manually adding in `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu trusty main` to my `sources.list` file to no avail.

How can I update PHP to 5.6.19 and make sure I don't run into this problem again in the future?

Comment: That repo only provides 5.6.18 at the moment. There's no guarantee to receive updates one day after a release. And you'll hardly find another which does. (Questions about where to find some software are off-scope for SO btw.)

Comment: @mario, thanks. So how can I update without having to use the repo?

Comment: Compile from source. Or use the [build tools](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial) and set up your own repo.

Answer (score 2):

The `ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6` repository is discontinued in favour of just `ppa:ondrej/php`. At the time of writing, this gives me an up-to-date version of PHP 5.6:

```
php --version
PHP 5.6.27-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
```

Note that, once you've added the repository, you'll need to uninstall any packages beginning `php5*` and reinstall `php5.6*` equivalents; also, you will probably have to switch Apache modules. More information on some of the steps required on [this blogpost](https://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/install-php-5-6-or-5-5-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-xenial-xerus/).

Note that, because of the quirk of the package maintainer's name containing a non-ASCII character, you might also need to install e.g. `language-pack-en` to fix all your server locales first. There's some other suggestions of what to do on [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/666754/unicodedecodeerror-in-ubuntu-while-installing-php5-6-from-ppa) but for me it was trivial to install the language pack and let that take care of all locale settings.